# How to implement a Icommand to add a new Customer?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, ef-code-first

I'm new to MVVM pattern, and I'm trying to implement a code that add a new Customer  to the Database.
I have 2 buttons and 2 textbox in my XAML file, one button is to update and the other is to add a new Customer with the Text of my textboxes. But when I click in the button "Add" nothing happens and the Customer is not added in my Database. I'm using EntityFramework and CodeFirst.
Here's my code:

Model:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<Customer> _customers;
    private Customer _currentCustomer;
    private CustomerRepository _repository;

    public CustomerViewModel()
    {
        _repository = new CustomerRepository();
        _customers = _repository.GeCustomers();
        WireCommands();
    }

    private void WireCommands()
    {
        UpdateCustomerCommand = new RelayCommand(UpdateCustomer);
    }

    public RelayCommand UpdateCustomerCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand AddCustomerCommand { get; private set; }

    public List<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return _customers; }
        set { _customers = value; }
    }

    public Customer CurrentCustomer
    {
        get { return _currentCustomer; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentCustomer != value)
            {
                _currentCustomer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentCustomer");
                UpdateCustomerCommand.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateCustomer()
    {
        _repository.UpdateCustomer(CurrentCustomer);
    }

    public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        _repository.NewCustomer(customer);

    }
```

Repository:

```
public List<Customer> GeCustomers()
    {
        return _customers;
    }

    public void UpdateCustomer(Customer SelectedCustomer)
    {
        Customer customerToChange = _customers.Single(c => c.CustomerId == SelectedCustomer.CustomerId);
        customerToChange = SelectedCustomer;
    }

    public void NewCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        _context.Customers.Add(customer);
        _context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

But, when I click the button nothing happens, and the Customer is not added in the Database.

Comment: Your AddCustomer command is not wired up... Anyway, when you still have a problem, use the Debugger and step through the whole thing. Also watch the Output window fro binding errors.

Comment: This worked thanks, but I'm have other question, how do the code knows that the text in the textbox is equal to my propertie of my class?

Comment: You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the Customer class (and/or on a specialized CustomerViewModel).